# Failed to create genesis block

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix

I tried creating genesis block. I have created a directory to store the chaindata. But on initializing genesis.json file I am getting this error:

> invalid genesis file:invalid character '<' looking for beginning of the value

Comment: There's an error in the genesis file. If you add it to the question we can check it.

Comment: Can you add your *genesis.json*?